# Distracted by or with

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Are there any differences between distracted by and distracted with?

For example:

> Don't distract yourselves **with** those phones.

Should it be **with** or **by** in the sentence above?

More:

> I get distracted by my phone really easily.
>
> How not to get distracted by the internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prepositions **by** and **with** are both considered prepositions of agent.

That's to say, they can both refer to situations where someone/something acts on someone/something else.

Which preposition you prefer depends on the context.

Your example:

> Don't distract yourselves with those phones

is correct.

To say: *Don't distract yourselves by those phones* sounds like *beside those phones*.

An internet search for *prepositions of agent* will offer you numerous examples of where either **by** or **with** is the correct choice.

Beware, however, of using prepositions of agent when you are talking about instruments.

One frequently comes across media examples of people saying things like: *killed by a sword* or *shot by a gun*, suggesting that swords and guns go around killing people.

There was a famous example when a BBC journalist asked a British politician after a political fracas whether he had been struck by a chair.

*No*, said the politician, correcting his questioner's English, *he had been struck by a man with a chair*.

http://english.edurite.com/english-grammar/preposition-of-agent.html